# How to ignore a directory or a file while running goimports?

Tags: go, gopath, goimports

I have the following project structure

```
proejct/
├── README.md
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── src
│   ├── delivery
│   │   ├── grpc
│   │   │   ├── index.go
│   │   │   ├── pb
│   │   │   │   ├── project.pb.go
│   │   │   │   └── another.pb.go
│   │   │   └── proto
│   │   │       ├── project.proto
│   │   │       └── another.proto
│   │   └── rest/
│   ├── main.go
│   └── .goimportsignore
└── .git/
```

I use `goimports` to manage the import lines in my source code. I want it to ignore the generated proto files (`*.pb.go`).

The [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports) says that

> To exclude directories in your $GOPATH from being scanned for Go files, goimports respects a configuration file at $GOPATH/src/.goimportsignore which may contain blank lines, comment lines (beginning with '#'), or lines naming a directory relative to the configuration file to ignore when scanning. No globbing or regex patterns are allowed. Use the "-v" verbose flag to verify it's working and see what goimports is doing.

So I set GOPATH to the root of the project in my terminal: `export GOPATH=$PWD` (yes, the `PWD` was correct). And added a `.goimportsignore` file in `src/` with the following contents:

```
delivery/grpc/pb
```

Now from the root of the project, I run `goimports -l -v ./`. No effect, I can still see .pb.go files in the list. I try `goimports -l -v src/` and still the same output. I tried moving the `.goimportsignore` file to project root and running the above commands. Again, I get the same output.

At this point, I am clueless to what I might be doing wrong. So, please help.

Comment: You shouldn’t be using GOPATH any longer, the goimports will use the current module.

Comment: @JimB I was just following the documentation. Where should I place the ignore file in my project with go modules?

Comment: `goimports` is currently not working with Go Modules. How to tackle this (and bigger design concerns) is being discussed [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/42965).